# Как построить семейное древо на html css или js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не один час сражаюсь с поиском, как построить такую диаграмму?
Много вариантов находил в том числе и на stackoverflow но не смог адаптировать.
Возможно ли сделать так чтоб человек переходил по ссылке и его имя было в центре?

Comment: Такую диаграмму можно построить на canvas либо используя css стили. Показывать имя можно только если мы как-то передадим в ссылке или при помощи авторизации на сайте имя пользователя

Comment: Спасибо за ответ